# How I can HTML Special Chars remove without image SRC in string?

Tags: php, html, string, special-characters, strip-tags

I tried to remove the HTML code in the string without remove the picture code

```
$HTMLstring = "<div class="h3 clr"><span>hello world</span><img src="/root/image.jpg"></div>

$plainText = htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($HTMLstring)));

$plainText // "hello world"
```

My Purpose: `$plainText // "hello world <img src="/root/image.jpg">"`

Okey but I lost image link. 
What should I do to prevent this part `<img src="/root/image.jpg">` from being remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip tags except those in 2nd parameter of `strip_tags()` :

```
$HTMLstring = '<div class="h3 clr"><span>hello world</span><img src="/root/image.jpg"></div>';
$AlwaysHTMLString = strip_tags($HTMLstring, '<img>');
echo $AlwaysHTMLString;
// hello world<img src="/root/image.jpg">
```

Don't use `htmlspecialchars()` or your `<img>` will not be rendered.

Comment: Thank you so much!